# VPN connection is using the internet connection of the remote desktop instead of my home internet connection

Tags: networking, vpn, internet, remote-desktop, remote-access

On my Windows 8.1 desktop at home I connect to a remote desktop outside my home network only to perform the tasks on the remote machine that are not network related (creating/updating/reading files etc). But at the same time when I browse the internet on my home desktop it seems the internet connection of the remote desktop is used since when I hover over the internet connection of my home desktop it reads "No internet access". But if I disconnect the remote desktop connection and hover over the internet connection of my home desktop it reads "Internet access". How can I make only my home internet connection to be used when I am browsing the internet on my home desktop while still connected to a remote desktop.

Answer (score 0):

https://serverfault.com/questions/626322/use-route-to-force-non-vpn-traffic-over-normal-connection-from-a-single-machine

route add -p IPADDRESSOFSERVER MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1 METRIC 1 IF 3

3 being the number of the wireless adaptor in the route print list.

Check `route print` to see the list of current routes. The `If` column will help you determine which one to use.